# why is Calendar.current.firstWeekday == 2?

Tags: swift, ios-simulator

In my playground, Calendar.current.firstWeekday == 1,  which I interpret as

> "Monday is the first day of the week where I live (Sweden)"

But when I run the simulator, Calendar.current.firstWeekday == **2**, and I don't understand why!  (In the simulator's *settings* I have set the region to "Sweden").

```
let c = Calendar.current
print(c) // prints "gregorian"
let first = Calendar.current.firstWeekday // this is 2 !!!
```

**Question:** Why is Calendar.current.firstWeekday == 2 and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> which I interpret as

I believe your interpretation is wrong. I'm not sure how the framework assigns the days of the week, but from your question I believe that they go 1 through 7, where 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday and so on. These are static and don't change with your settings.

The `firstWeekday` property tells you what day of the week the week starts in your locale. In the US, which is the default locale, a week starts on Sunday.

You can't "fix this" because nothing is wrong, that property is there to provide you with information which is specially useful when drawing a calendar.

Comment: +1 , Thanks this might be the answer. I was assuming that 0 was the first day of the week, but if it is 1 then it would explain everything!

Comment: It's unusual because we are so used to indices starting with 0 but I just tried this on a playground and indeed, saturday is 7 and sunday is 1.

Comment: But in the list I got from DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols, Sunday is day 0 :-(

Comment: @ragnarius `weekdaySymbols` is an array. Array indexes start at 0. That has nothing to do with the values returned by the `firstWeekday` property.

Comment: yes, but in the programming language C (or swift) everything should start on 0. So I found it confusing  that the days started by 1.

Comment: @ragnarius I think your best bet to get the actual name of the day of the week from a date would be to use a `DateFormatter` with the format `EEEE` or `EE` for an abbreviation.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out the user-setting for start of the week?

Comment: @Georg that's exactly what `firstWeekday` does

Comment: No, it won't change if I change the first weekday in the calendar section of iOS...

Answer (score 4):

In the playground, the locale is set, as a default, to the US localization. Hence, it says that the first day of the week is 1/Sunday, which is the case in the US.

When you ran the code in the simulator, that HAD been set to Sweeden, you're told that the first day of the week is 2/Monday, which is the case in Sweden.

The discrepancy is due to the fact that the playground defaults to a US localization. If you'd like the playground to act as though it is in Sweden, you'll have to put that in code.

Comment: +1, thanks, I think my main problem is that the weekdays are 1..7 and not 0..6, which would be more natural in swift.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case.
To get all possible variations of the first weekday for all available countries:

Choose your locale or get current then enjoy results.

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US") 

Locale.availableIdentifiers
    .map { Locale(identifier:$0) }
    .reduce([:]) { result, value -> [Int: [String]] in
        var newResult = result

        let weekday = value.calendar.firstWeekday

        if var existing = newResult[weekday] {
            existing.append(value.identifier)
            newResult[weekday] = existing
            return newResult
        }

        newResult[weekday] = [value.identifier]
        return newResult
    }
    .sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
    .forEach { weekday, locales in
        let locDescr = locales.map {
            locale.localizedString(forIdentifier: $0)
        }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        
        print("Weekday \(weekday) :\n \(locDescr)\n\n")
    }
```